# Help solving the following equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to solve the following equality:

$$
\frac{x^2 - 3x}{x-2} + \frac{x-2}{x^2 - 3x} = \frac{5}{2}
$$

My idea was to make $x$ a common factor in $x^2 - 3x$ and than group them somehow but no luck. I'm guessing that this could be solved by simply solving the sum but I don't think that this is the purpose of this exercise.

Comment: First solve $y +\frac1y = \frac52$.

Comment: Here you have an equality not an inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Follwing Daniel Fischer's suggestion,*
Set $A:= \dfrac{x^2-3x}{x-2}$.
Then your equation is:
$$
A + \frac{1}{A} = \frac{5}{2}
$$
So, $$\frac{A^2+1}{A} = \frac{5}{2}$$ Which implies
$$
5A = 2A^2 + 2 \Longrightarrow 2A^2-5A+2 = 0
$$
Henceforth
$$
(2A-1)(A-2)=0
$$
So
$$
A=\frac{1}{2} \text{ or } A = 2
$$
Now solve these.

Comment: Thank you! It was easier than I expected

Comment: @user84469 you're welcome! Thanks to Daniel Fischer for pointing out my damned typos.

Comment: @BabakS. Viva Babak!